# How to apply time between two pushpin?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am very new to wp7.

**Requirement:** Display data on bing map when value of date is changed and when data is displayed on bing map then create a new pushpin button at a particular position. When the button is clicked, it should show the location, latitude and longitude in a messagebox.

But this work is done. Now I have one play button; when play button is pressed then data comes automatically on bing map but some time difference is required. So how do I give time between two pushpin?

My C# code is:

```
 for (int i = 0; i <= ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLongLatitude.Count-1; i++)
 {
     string lat, lon;
     lat = ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLatitude.ElementAt<string>(i).Trim();
     lon = ClsGetDeviceMap.lstLongLatitude.ElementAt<string>(i).Trim();
     Latitude = Convert.ToDouble(lat);
     LongLatitude = Convert.ToDouble(lon);
     GpsSpeed = 44.21811;

     map1.Center = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, LongLatitude, GpsSpeed);
     map1.ZoomLevel = 17;
     map1.ZoomBarVisibility = Visibility.Visible;

     pin[i] = new Pushpin();
     pin[i].Location = new GeoCoordinate(Latitude, LongLatitude);



     map1.Children.Add(pin[i]);
     myCoorditeWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
     myCoorditeWatcher.MovementThreshold = 20;


     var gl = GestureService.GetGestureListener(pin[i]);
     gl.Hold += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(GestureListener_Hold);
     gl.Tap += new EventHandler<GestureEventArgs>(GestureListener_Stack_Tap);
```